# BigQuery Error: Destination deleted/expired during execution

Tags: google-bigquery

I've a batch script to load data from google cloud bucket to a table in big query. A scheduled SSIS job executes this batch file daily.

`bq load -F "\t" --encoding=UTF-8 --replace=true db_name.tbl_name gs://GSCloudBucket/file.txt "column1:string, column2:string, column3:string"`

Weirdly, the execution is successful some days and not some other time. Here is what I have on the log.

Waiting on bqjob_r790a43a4_00000155a65559c2_1 ... (0s) Current status: RUNNING ......
Waiting on bqjob_r790a43a4_00000155a65559c2_1 ... (7s) Current status: DONE

**BigQuery error in load operation: Error processing job: Destination
deleted/expired during execution**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one option is if you have 1 day (or multiple of days) expiration on that table (either on table directly or via default expiration on dataset). In this case - because actual time of load very you can get to situation when destination table has expired by that time.

You can use [configuration.load.createDisposition](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#configuration.load.createDisposition) attribute to address this.
Or/and you can make sure you have proper expiration set - for daily process it would be let's say - 26 hours  - so you have extra 2 hours for your SSIS job to complete before table can expire

Comment: I have the same error in a query job. I set the create disposition to CREATE_IF_NEEDED and write disposition to WRITE_TRUNCATE. The table expiration is 1 day. The query finishes in about 45 minutes with this error. The job is to write the result into the table. Any ideas on how to find the root cause?